# Classpath search using System.getProperty("java.class.path") does search MANIFEST

Tags: java

I have this line of code:

```
private static final String CLASSPATH = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

and my jar is built so that the CLASSPATH is included in the manifest:

```
Built-By: john
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_75
Class-Path: lib/json-20151123.jar lib/testng-6.9.10.jar lib/jcommander
 -1.48.jar lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar lib/jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar lib/netty
  -3.8.0.Final.jar lib/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar lib/jboss-jaxrs-ap
  i_2.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar lib/resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.14.Final.jar lib/jc
  ip-annotations-1.0.jar lib/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final
  .jar lib/resteasy-netty-3.0.14.Final.jar lib/resteasy-client-3.0.14.F
  inal.jar lib/resteasy-jaxb-provider-3.0.14.Final.jar lib/resteasy-jac
```

This classpath does not appear to be included in java.class.path...
Is there any way to add it?

Comment: Maybe you should better describe what you want to achive. Which classpath declaration you want to add to what and why?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the application with `java -jar your.jar ...` then the JVM option `-classpath` is ignored.

If you run the application with `java -cp your.jar a.class.inside.the.jar` then the `Class-Path` header from the `MANIFEST.MF` is ignored.